# Redirect the bare domain to a subdomain and still make the bare domain appear to users to fix a CSP error that occurs when using the bare domain?

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'd be grateful for some guidance with URL redirects in the `.htaccess` files as I'm not sure how to handle (though I hope it's straightforward).

I've installed a site into a subdomain, let's call it `website.example.com`, and I need calls to `example.com` to be redirected to `website.example.com`.

Also need `example.com/mypage` to redirect to `website.example.com/mypage`, etc.

And finally, for the "website" part to be hidden so it just looks like everything is at the top level.

I think it's a combination of `RrewiteRule`s and `RewriteBase` that is needed, but not sure how to complete it.

Comment: I don't think you actually want what you say you want.  It sounds like you actually want `example.com` to serve your content directly.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller There's technical reason it can't be held in example.com. There's a component I'm using that doesn't work in the root but does in a subdomain. I tried it all in the root originally.

Comment: Can you go into more detail about this component and what didn't work?  Redirects change the URL that is visible to users, so what you want isn't possible.  But we might be able to find a fix to your component.  It is also very common to host your website on the `www.` subdomain and redirect the bare domain to it.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I appreciate your help. In short, I am using the Joomla CMS with a blogging component called EasyBlog. It allows the insertion of code blocks which seem to use the Ace Editor, but when called from the website root (public_html) causes an error (eval() blocked by CSP). However, it works correctly when the site is installed into a subdomain.

Comment: Which Joomla plugin are you using to manage your content security policies (CSP)?

Comment: According to [this article](https://magazine.joomla.org/all-issues/june-2020/j4-using-the-security-header-features) starting in Joomla 4 there are a bunch of CSP settings built in.

Comment: I didn't know this until you flagged it up. TBH I don't have a clue what to set to rectify the problem.

Comment: Simple answer: you shouldn't do what you want to do. The only way to implement what you want, is to use an iframe. You can then have the user visit example.com, but in reality, he's browsing website.example.com - HOWEVER, this is not a best practice approach, your website might be flagged or demoted in search engines, and generally doesn't provide for a good user experience.